# Is the using same techniques considered plagiarisim?

Tags: phd, research-process, thesis, plagiarism

A geologist used some techniques to investigate certain oil field for his PhD thesis. If another geologist useS the same techniques but for a different oil field can it be considered plagiarism?

Comment: Did you read the definition of plagiarism on wikipedia? What do you think? Why would it be plagiarism and why not? We are not going to google for you.

Comment: @Louic I have confused. I need a straight answer.

Comment: You have received a straight answer. That straight answer is: look at the definition of plagiarism on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism

Answer (score 3):

If you cite the early work and explain that you are using the same technique, then no, it isn't plagiarism. But it may not be "novel" enough for publication, though that depends on the details and the judgement of reviewers. And for a thesis, it depends on the judgement of advisors and examiners. The standards there can be different from publication standards.

It might have an economic benefit, of course.

Plagiarism is about claiming ideas of others as your own. If you cite the early work then it isn't plagiarism.